# Maven dependency version

Tags: java, maven

When doing a `mvn clean install -U` I am getting:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project xxx-security: Could not resolve dependencies for project xxx:xxx-security:jar:50-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at
xxx:xxx-persistence:jar:50-SNAPSHOT -> org.mybatis:mybatis:jar:${mybatis.version}: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.mybatis:mybatis:jar:${mybatis.version}: Could not
transfer artifact org.mybatis:mybatis:pom:${mybatis.version} from/to nexus (http://example.net/repository/Standard/): Failed to transfer file: http://example.net/repository/Stan
dard/org/mybatis/mybatis/$%7Bmybatis.version%7D/mybatis-$%7Bmybatis.version%7D.pom. Return code is: 400 , ReasonPhrase:Invalid repository path. -> [Help 1]
```

What I don't get is why maven is using mybatis.version in the url to get the dependency rather than a version number. I have searched the code and cannot find mybatis.version in there. I did find:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
   <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

So why is maven using mybatis.version rather than 3.0.4?

Comment: Did you run a maven update on your project?

Comment: is that part of the pom you posted in the `dependencyManagement` tag perhaps?

Comment: Return code is: 400 , ReasonPhrase:Invalid repository path. Please take a look at the repository definitions in your pom.xml

Comment: @DavidWeber we can see that. The reason is that the `${mybatis.version}` property is not being resolved.

Comment: What happens if you define the `<mybatis.version>3.0.4</mybatis.version>` property? It's difficult to debug your issue without seeing the whole source code.

Comment: @f1sh Is "mybatis.version" defined as a property in your properties tag in your pom.xml?

Comment: @DavidWeber it's not my question, but OP states "I have searched the code and cannot find mybatis.version in there". Have you read the question?

Comment: `mybatis-$%7Bmybatis.version%7D.pom.` this looks you are trying to use ci friendly but not correct?

Comment: @f1sh Yes I read the question. I asked this because of control. Was this property some time ago defined in your pom.xml and was then removed? Did the person which removed this property eventually did not run a maven update on this project? This could be the root of the problem. So please run a maven update, clean the project and try again with the additional switch "-x". And then post your full stacktrace.

Comment: Not sure what the gremlins were but deleting out my .m2/repository folder and running maven again sorted it out

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `xxx:xxx-persistence:jar:50-SNAPSHOT` jar has internal dependency with `org.mybatis:mybatis:jar:${mybatis.version}`. Provided that you define `mybatis.version` in your properties.

You can do following:

1. Execute `mvn dependency:tree` to check which specific jar has this dependency.
2. Also define `<mybatis.version>3.0.4</mybatis.version>` under  `<properties>` section of `pom.xml`. You can optionally remove `<version>3.0.4</version>` from your `<dependency>` section where you defined `mybatis` dependency.